# IIS returns 503 on ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, security, iis

I have an ASP.NET MVC site. This site has been copied to C:\MyWebSite

I made an app pool AAA for this, with a user account from a domain.

I granted this user account ACL rights to C:\MyWebSite for read&execute & list.

After I visit the website, I get a 503 error Service Not Available.

The error in the System event log says:

> The identity of application pool AAA is invalid. The user name or
>   password that is specified for the identity may be incorrect, or the
>   user may not have batch logon rights. If the identity is not
>   corrected, the application pool will be disabled when the application
>   pool receives its first request.  If batch logon rights are causing
>   the problem, the identity in the IIS configuration store must be
>   changed after rights have been granted before Windows Process
>   Activation Service (WAS) can retry the logon. If the identity remains
>   invalid after the first request for the application pool is processed,
>   the application pool will be disabled. The data field contains the
>   error number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Verify the password you used when you added the user to the app pool.
  It is cached and if wrong it will not fix it self, try to
  re-authenticate and associate.
- Check if user has batch logon rights
- Verify ACL rights the application directory

Comment: Done that, but doesn't fix.

Comment: If you run as local service or network service does it work correctly?

Comment: As Local Service it runs

Comment: "or the user may not have batch logon rights." have you checked this?

Comment: that might be, but i cannot add the user to this local security policy item; the add button has been grayed out....

Comment: I found a way to edit this local security policy. It is part of a GPO. I created a specific GPO, added the accounts to 'logon as a batch job', 'logon as a service' and 'deny log on locally' and linked the GPO to my domain, restarted the server, and it works!

Answer (score 0):

Check if the application pool is running.

Comment: The app pool is running and the app pools are part of the IIS group